# Is it possible to detect what is toggled at the current cursor location in designMode?

Tags: javascript, contenteditable, richtext

I am working on a customized rich text editor and I am wondering if it is possible to place my cursor somewhere and discover what commands (i.e. bold, italic, justifyCenter, etc.) are currently active/toggled. Obviously, the browser, while in designMode, is keeping track of this. For example, if I have text inside of the iframe like this:

hello **world**!

and then i place my cursor inside of the word "world", is there any way to figure out that 'bold' is currently toggled without parsing the string and discovering that I am between  tags?

The reason I want something like this is so that I can detect a selectionchange event on the editor and then highlight the appropriate button(s) corresponding to what is currently toggled at that position

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `queryCommandState()` method of `document` does this:

```
var isBold = document.queryCommandState("bold");
```

See [MDC](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Midas), [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536679%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and [Dottoro](http://help.dottoro.com/ljkxwclp.php).

Comment: Thanks! This led me down the path to find the queryCommandValue method, which I think will work perfectly!